# How can I use JHtml to create Vertical Tabs

Tags: jhtml

Using this standard JHtml code, I can generate *Horizontal* tabs (across the top) without problem.  I've been tinkering with the `$options` array to set it up, but JHtml seems to have changed a bunch, and I don't seem to be able to find the secret combination of settings to get *Vertical* tabs instead.

[image]

**JHtml that renders *Horizontal* Tabs**

```
$options = array(
    'useCookie' => true, // this must not be a string. Don't use quotes.
);
echo JHtml::_('tabs.start', 'tab_group_id', $options);
echo JHtml::_('tabs.panel', 'Tab Heading 1', 'panel_1_id');
echo 'Panel 1 content goes here.';
echo JHtml::_('tabs.panel', 'Tab Heading 2', 'panel_2_id');
echo 'Panel 2 content goes here.';
echo JHtml::_('tabs.panel', 'Tab Heading 3', 'panel_3_id');
echo 'Panel 3 content goes here.';
echo JHtml::_('tabs.end');
```

**HTML that renders the desired *Vertical* tabs**

```
<div id="my-panels" class="tabbable tabs-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#panel_1_id" data-toggle="tab">Tab Heading 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#panel_2_id" data-toggle="tab">Tab Heading 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#panel_3_id" data-toggle="tab">Tab Heading 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="panel_1_id">Some Content1</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="panel_2_id">Some Content2</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="panel_3_id">Some Content3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it something in `$options` that has to be set, or is it something else altogether in JHtml that I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are using the Joomla 3.0 method for adding tabs. There is a newer method as of Joomla 3.1 which unfortunately is not documented at all apart from the API page.

With the new tab method, all you need to do is wrap it round a `div` with a specific class like so:

```
$options = array(
    'useCookie' => true,
    'active' => 'tabs_1'
);

// Start Tabs
echo '<div class="tabbable tabs-left">';
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.startTabSet', 'tab_group_id', $options);

// Tab 1
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'tab_group_id', 'tabs_1', 'Tab 1');
echo '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>';
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab');

// Tab 2
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'tab_group_id', 'tabs_2', 'Tab 2');
echo '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>';
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab');

// End Tabs
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTabSet');
echo '</div>';
```

Tested and working in Joomla 3.3.6

#### Update:

If you wish you style the tabs in some way, shape or form, you can simply add a class to the `div` wrapper like so:

```
echo '<div class="tabbable tabs-left gdp-tabs">';
```

and then to style the `a` or `li` elements, simply use:

```
.gdp-tabs li {
   //code here
}
.gdp-tabs li a {
   //code here
}
```

Comment: http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:FLWS

Comment: Lol, well I think an included vase would be nice so I'll take these: http://www.interflora.co.uk/product/orchids/luxury-orchid-and-rose-arrangement/

Comment: I noticed that this doesn't add IDs to any of the LI or A items.  Is there a way to add classes or IDs to the tabs to apply CSS or use jQuery for selected items?

Comment: @GDP - I know you know the answer to that ;) I'll post for info for this in an hour if you still require it

Comment: Ah...the Yoda-Of-Front-End-Development is going to make the lowly systems guy sweat, huh?

Comment: @GDP - Updated the answer for you.

Comment: Okay...couldn't see the trees for the forest for styling, but really interested in id's for specialized jquery (and maybe CSS)

Comment: @GDP - If you could share what exactly you wish to do using jQuery, I could provide you with an alternative as supposed to adding ID's to the `li` or `a` elements

Comment: nothing specific, more for the question and general knowledge.  It just surprises me that its not built in.

Comment: back to working on this part of my component, so am going to create a new question about the IDs and jQuery/CSS with "my" solution - will be interested how you grade it, lol.